# How can I send a mail with a condition?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like the message to be sent when there is a value in column H, for example "y"  ->   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGGSF.png)

Sub sendCustEmails()

```
Dim objOutlook As Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim objEmail As Object
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(oMailItem)
Dim strMailBody As String

intRow = 2
strISO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS_Data").Range("B" & intRow).Text

While (strISO <> "")

Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(oMailItem)

StrMailSubject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mail_Details").Range("A2").Text
 strMailBody = "<BODY style='font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri(Body)'>" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mail_Details").Range("B2").Text & "</BODY>"
strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, Chr(10), "<br>")

strFolder = "C:\Users\CIOTTIC\OneDrive - IAEA\Desktop\AL TEST"
strISO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS_Data").Range("B" & intRow).Text
strSalutation = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS_Data").Range("C" & intRow).Text
strEmail = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS_Data").Range("D" & intRow).Text
strCC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS_Data").Range("E" & intRow).Text
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS_Data").Range("F" & intRow).Text
strFile2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS_Data").Range("G" & intRow).Text

StrMailSubject = Replace(StrMailSubject, "<ISO>", strISO)
strMailBody = Replace(strMailBody, "<Salutation>", strSalutation)

With objEmail
   .To = CStr(strEmail)
   .CC = CStr(strCC)
   .Subject = StrMailSubject
   .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
   .Display
   .Attachments.Add strFolder & "\" & strFile
   .Attachments.Add strFolder & "\" & strFile2
   .HTMLBody = strMailBody & .HTMLBody
   .Send
   
End With

     intRow = intRow + 1
     strISO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS_Data").Range("B" & intRow).Text
```

Wend
MsgBox "Done"

End Sub

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, hope is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
Sub Test()

If Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
    GoTo SendEmail
    Else: Exit Sub
End If
Send Email:
'Enter the rest of your code here.
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried but It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant


Private Sub sendCustEmails_WithCondition()

' Late binding
Dim objOutlook As Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim objEmail As Object

Dim strISO As String
Dim strMailSubject As String

Dim longRow As Long
longRow = 2

strISO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS_Data").Range("B" & longRow).Text
Debug.Print "strISO: " & strISO

While (strISO <> "")
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS_Data").Range("H" & longRow).Text = "Y" Then
    
        'Typo - use Option Explicit
        'Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(oMailItem)
        ' For early binding oMailItem should be olMailItem
        
        ' This is "accepted" in late binding without Option Explicit.
        ' Appears the variable "oMailItem" which is empty is treated as a zero.
        
        Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
                
        'strMailSubject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mail_Details").Range("A2").Text
        strMailSubject = "Subject is <ISO>"
                        
        strISO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS_Data").Range("B" & longRow).Text
        
        strMailSubject = Replace(strMailSubject, "<ISO>", strISO)
        Debug.Print " strMailSubject: " & strMailSubject
                
        With objEmail
            .Subject = strMailSubject
            .Display
        End With

    Else
    
        ' Not Y
        Debug.Print " No mail."
        
    End If

    longRow = longRow + 1
    strISO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS_Data").Range("B" & longRow).Text
    Debug.Print "strISO: " & strISO
    
Wend

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```